# I described text as sounding a certain way and someone said “I can’t hear him” what is what he did called?

Tags: sounds

This occurring on a thread of messages and someone previously commented and I replied mentioning they “sounded mad.” Someone then replied, “How is he sounding? I can’t hear him” What is what they did called? Oh- and bonus points, what’s it called when I “heard” the way someone was “sounding” in text?

Comment: They did a lot of things - which thing are you asking about?

Comment: As it stands, your question needs to be more clearly explained.  You obviously used the word 'sounded' metaphorically to apply to something read rather than heard.  Someone else (I assume in jest) chose to take your remark literally.  What exactly is it you want to know?  If there is a word for this type of humour (affecting to understand a metaphor literally) I do not know it.

Comment: My apologies, I suppose I thought it was more complex than me just calling it ‘they took it literally’ thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

The way somebody would *sound* if they were speaking (and the emotion they would convey), which is frequently unknown from plain text, is **intonation** or **tone of voice**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> *[intonation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intonation)*:
> **4** : manner of utterance
> *specifically* : the rise and fall in pitch of the voice in speech
>
> [*tone of voice*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tone%20of%20voice):
> : the way a person is speaking to someone
> // I don't like your *tone of voice*.

---

It's possible to have the following commentary over a *text* exchange:

> A: "He sounds mad."
> B: "How can you tell? I don't hear anything."

What B does in this situation is to make a joke based on a [**literal-minded**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literal-minded) interpretation of the words:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : understanding words and statements only in the most basic and ordinary way and not having much imagination

It's a form of [pun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pun). A pun is where you take the assumed meaning of a word and, in a punch line, change it into a different and unexpected meaning. But, in this case, it's choosing to play dumb and simply not understand the meaning of *sound* in its figurative context, and use its literal context instead.